# Accessing the status of parallel queries/mutations in RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

While using the RTK Query, I faced the following problem: I have a user interface with a list of devices, and I want to be able to select multiple devices in the list, run some action on them, and show the loading spinner for each device for which the action is performed. To do this, I have to make several parallel requests to some endpoint on the backend like this:

```
const [pullDeviceConfig, pullDeviceConfigResult] = usePullDeviceConfigMutation()

const handlePullConfig = async () => {
    const promises = selectedIds.map(async id => {
        const result = await pullDeviceConfig({
            'device_id': id
        })

        if (result.data) {
            ...
        }

        if (result.error) {
            ...
        }
    })

    await Promise.all(promises)
}
```

And everything is fine, but since each request has a different duration, in order to correctly display the status by loading spinners, I need to be able to get isLoading state of each independent running mutation. Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to do this in RTK Query.
For an example in a competing library React Query, you can use `useQueries` hook that gives you an Array of results, and access isLoading state for each independent query like this:

```
const isLoading = queryResults.some(query => query.isLoading)
```

But is there a way to do the same for queries/mutations in RTK Query?